# Science fiction novel where a man and woman travel through a gateway to other planets and the Earth is controlled by a computer

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

There are characters named Eric and Lisa. Eric sees Lisa being driven by, while at a bar with friends. He falls in love and tries to find her. He hires a detective who finds her but tells Eric not to pursue Her. He ignores this. The detective is killed. Eric locates Lisa and fights for her. Eventually, they escape by using a gateway to another planet. The planet is a paradise where they get with the people there, then return to Earth and go through the gateway to another planet. The planet Earth is controlled by a computer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is very probably *[The I Inside](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3438)* by Alan Dean Foster, first published in 1984.

"Eric" is Eric Abbott, who falls in love with Lisa Tambor when he glimpses her face through the tinted windows of her car as he is crossing the street. He attempts to track her down, firstly by hiring a private investigator called Polikartos who after making some preliminary inquiries indeed advises him not to pursue the matter:

> "Just forget all about this. You seem like a nice young fellow. You
> listen to me, yes, and forget about this woman, forget about the car
> you saw, forget the whole business, hokay?"

Eric pays Polikartos to continue with the investigation, and the detective is killed. The rest of the book is essentially Eric's quest to find Lisa. The world is ruled by a supercomputer called Colligatarch, and a major plotpoint is the "GATE": a way of traveling to the colony planets, "Garden" and "Eden".

Comment: You can have this one :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie That's very generous of you! If (or rather, when) we clash next time I'll concede to you. Don't let me forget.

Comment: thanks thats the book. appreciate the help